# How to assert (listof? string?) predicate in Typed Racket

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I have a list of optional strings in a typed racket program, i.e.

```lisp
statements : (Listof (Option String))
```

I have another function that takes a `(Listof String)` and I know that unless an exception is raised, all of the strings in statements are present. I'd like to assert this fact, but I don't see how to assert a predicate like `(listof? string?)` for example to prove this to typed racket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write one:

```
(define (listof-string? (l : (Listof Any)))
  (andmap string? l))
```

Then:

```
(define (bar (x : (Listof String)))
  x)

(define (foo (x : (Listof (Option String))))
  (bar (assert x listof-string?)))
```

will typecheck.